# How to measure antenna resonant frequency using an USRP?

Tags: frequency, usrp

Has any of you used an USRP to estimate resonant frequency of antenna? 
My objective is to measure the frequency of my MIFA antenna, so I tried the whip antenna first to learn how to do it properly. I did the following steps but it showed that even the frequency of a commercial 2.4GHz antenna is not 2.4, but 3.1GHz.

(1) I used a rubber band to tie a 2.4GHz Tx antenna and a 2.4GHz Rx antenna (with 26dB attenuation)

(2) Start both Tx and Rx using a GNURadio graph

(3) Change the Tx and Rx frequency manually using a slider in the graph

At each Tx/Rx frequency, I observe the spectrum of the Rx, but consider only the center frequency (max value). What I found is that this value is not the highest at 2.4GHz (-35dB) compared to the other center frequencies. The highest one is at 3.1GHz (-25dB).

Can any one give me some explanations or some clues to measure the resonant frequency of an antenna using an USRP? (I don't have a VNA)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of: your measurement setup has physically nothing to do with the resonant frequency of the antennas. For several reasons:

1. not every antenna is a resonant one.
2. by binding two antennas to each other, you're not measuring the properties of either antenna, you're building some strange, undefined coupled system that has nothing to do with how the antennas behave when used as antenna. It's called "reactive near field" for a reason!
3. Even if that wasn't the problem, you're ignoring the amount of power converted to heat, so you're neglecting antenna efficiency while trying to measure something that incorporates antenna efficiency (namely, the Q factor of the antenna).

---

Short answer: you can't, since USRPs aren't calibrated, and have different gain on different frequencies.

Longer answer: you'd need a completely different setup (see above), and probably a different USRP (you forgot to tell us which USRP you are using, there are many).

You'll need directive couplers to measure the S11 of the TX antenna, and see where that takes a strong dip. That's typically the resonant frequency. Again, not all antennas *are* resonant, and there's a lot of engineering tradeoffs that would lead one to not operate the antenna at a resonant peak (bandwidth, mechanical size, stability, uniformity of gain, …).